# Google font in MailMessage c# asp.net

Tags: c#, html, asp.net, fonts, mailmessage

Hi is there a way to include a font in the MailMessage from and external URL? 
e.g

```
 <link href=""https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto"" rel=""stylesheet""/>
```

Thank you

Comment: There is no point really. I don't think much email clients will support it.

Comment: oh ok so there is no way to use custom google fonts?

Comment: Best forget it. Read https://www.campaignmonitor.com/css/ and https://css-tricks.com/using-css-in-html-emails-the-real-story/

Comment: well that is a shame..